# R: Efficient way for replacing strings in a data frame(table)

Tags: r, string

Here's the code for the issue:

```
set.seed(1234)
y <- 1e7

renamer <- function(text){
  text[grep("ac", text)] <- "aaa"
  text[grep("gf", text)] <- "bbb"
  text[grep("er", text)] <- "ccc"
  text[grep("hy", text)] <- "ddd"
  text[grep("nh", text)] <- "eee"
  text[grep("oi", text)] <- "fff"
  text[grep("nu", text)] <- "ggg"
  text[grep("vf", text)] <- "hhh"
  text[grep("cd", text)] <- "iii"
  text[grep("po", text)] <- "jjj"
  return(text)
}

smp <- NULL
for(i in 1:100){
  smp <- c(smp, paste0(sample(letters, 15, T), collapse= ""))
}

df <- data.table(a = sample(smp, y, T))

# > system.time(renamer(text = df$a))
# user  system elapsed 
# 15.54    0.08   15.70
```

Problem: there's a large data set that requires most of their values replaced in a time efficient manner. My code does the trick.. however, I really could use a faster solution.

Note that there are reoccurring values. And... (as it sometimes happens) while I was writing this question, I probably came up with solution which includes converting column to factor and replacing level values. But I decided to leave this question anyways, as someone else might need a help on this problem or there is some clever alternative solution.

Here's a factor solution for benchmark:

```
# > system.time({
#   +   df$a <- factor(df$a)
#   +   levels(df$a) <- renamer(levels(df$a))
#   +   df$a <- as.character(df$a)
#   + })
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.25    0.14    1.42
```

Comment: Do you have a fixed list of values and their lookup?

Comment: `renamer()` function is always the same. Data, however, may differ. Data might aswell not contain any of those values that function is looking for. Or it can replace all of the values.

Comment: So just create a lookup table and then use `stringi::stri_detect_fixed`. For instance, this runs in no time on my machine `renamer <- cbind(Lookup = sapply(letters[1:10], function(x) paste0(rep(x, each = 3), collapse = "")), Values = c("ac", "gf", "er", "hy", "nh", "oi", "nu", "vf", "cd", "po")) ; system.time(df[, Result := renamer[stringi::stri_detect_fixed(a, renamer[, "Values"]), "Lookup"], by = a])`

Comment: That is actually pretty cool, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a simple lookup table and use the excellent `stringi::stri_detect_fixed` function (gives me ~X100 speedup)

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

Lookup <- c("ac", "gf", "er", "hy", "nh", "oi", "nu", "vf", "cd", "po")
Rename <- substring(paste(rep(letters[1:10], each = 3), collapse = ""), 
                    seq(1, 30 ,3), seq(3, 30, 3))


system.time(setDT(df)[, Result := Rename[stri_detect_fixed(a, Lookup)], by = a])
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.10    0.05    0.14
```